# How to view detailed data in Kusto, using the Python kusto SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have used the following packages

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.exceptions import KustoServiceError
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
```

I would like to see the detailed output of the results, but I followed the official tutorial and I am not sure if I am correct

```
x = dataframe_from_result_table(response.primary_results[0])
```

His results look like this

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Resource]
Index: []
```

Is this result wrong or normal?
If it is normal, how do I call them?  What would it look like if the executed database had output?

I want to see the content of the Resource in the specified content: Columns: [Resource], because this will have the output I want. I am using translation software, please understand

Officially, I can manipulate the data according to the python panda, but I won't be able to call out the data

[kusto query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmI94.png)

When I use other query statements. The result shows

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Tag,Level,Sequence,Message,Metrics]
Index: []
```

How do I retrieve the values of Tag, Level, Sequence, Message, Metrics from the results?

[The result class looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkZcl.jpg)

Comment: "I followed the official tutorial" - please give provide the relevant link

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/data-explorer/python-query-data
  
When I use kusto Data Explorer. it returns a result. But I don't use python to return results

Comment: How do expect to retrieve values from an empty DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the publicly available [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-ui-samples-gallery) cluster.
Please note that the connection requires an interactive login.
A login window will pop when you execute the code.

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table

cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net"

db = "Samples"

query = """
StormEvents
| summarize count() by EventType 
| top 5 by count_
"""

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_interactive_login(cluster)
client = KustoClient(kcsb)

response = client.execute(db, query)

df = dataframe_from_result_table(response.primary_results[0])

print(df)
```

```
           EventType  count_
0  Thunderstorm Wind   13015
1               Hail   12711
2        Flash Flood    3688
3            Drought    3616
4     Winter Weather    3349
```

P.S.
Another option is to leverage the [KWE](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/) (Kusto Web Explorer) experience.
Get your own [free cluster](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/freecluster) and easily ingest data using [OneClick](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/oneclick/ingest?sourceType=file).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, yes, the query works fine. But my code is not outputting the above result. I want to see the content of the Resource in the specified content: Columns: [Resource], because this will have the output I want. I am using translation software, please understand

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your issue. This code works with the exact same data as in the linked you posted in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I probably need to make my question clearer, that was my mistake. What I want to achieve is that I need to use python kusto to perform tedious query operations instead of me, because I have hundreds of statements to query, so I want to get the data queried in kusto Data Explorer through python (I do not need to extract the data to calculate), just want to get the results of the query statements, because if there are my If there is an error in my sql statement in kusto, I need to feed this problem to other engineers in my group

Comment: So, what is the question? If you know how to execute a single query, you should be able to execute multiple queries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I checked it was a mistake in my KQL statement writing. Thank you for your help, thank you very much, I am using translation software, please understand